# Is there an analogue of the hive model for Littlewood-Richardson coefficients of types $B$, $C$ and $D$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, littlewood-richardson-coefficients

If $V_\lambda$, $V_\mu$ and $V_\nu$ are irreducible representations of $\operatorname{GL}_n$, the Littlewood-Richardson coefficient $c_{\lambda\mu}^\nu$ denotes the multiplicity of  $V_\nu$ in the direct sum decomposition of the tensor product of $V_\lambda$ and $V_\nu$.
Knutson and Tao (JAMS 1999, [link at AMS site](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1999-12-04/S0894-0347-99-00299-4/S0894-0347-99-00299-4.pdf)) proposed a  "hive model" for Littlewood-Richardson coefficients.

Is there an analogous model for such tensor product multiplicities for Lie groups of types B, C or D?

Answer (score 11):

The recent work of [Goncharov-Shen](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5922) gives a good generalization of the hive model for any reductive group $ G$.  They show that $n$-fold tensor product multiplicities for $ G $ are counted by positive tropical integral points of the space $ G^\vee \setminus ( G^\vee / N)^n $.  When $ G = GL_m$ and $n = 3$, this gives the Hive model.  When $ G = GL_m $ and $ n = 4 $, this gives the octahedron recurrence.

Unfortunately, outside of type $ A$, it is hard to give a simple description of their set of positive tropical points.  To do so requires some choices, and once one makes these choices, you end up with one of the Berenstein-Zelevinsky models which Allen mentioned.

Answer (score 9):

There are conjectural ones in the Berenstein-Zelevinsky paper referenced in that one. They have another paper with a general theorem, *[Tensor product multiplicities, canonical bases and totally positive varieties](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9912012)* (Inventiones mathematicae **143** (2001) pp 77–128, https://doi.org/10.1007/s002220000102), that gives (many) polyhedral models for any Lie type.

Comment: Hi Allen,
Thank you very much. I think I heard that there may be a model for type B, where 3 hives are pasted together to form a Moebius strip, but otherwise the model is similar to the hive model for type A. I'd be very grateful if you could clarify if this is the case.

Answer (score 6):

There is some recent progress on this question.  JiaRui Fei https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02521.pdf has given a generalization of the hive model for all semisimple Lie algebras, based on the theory of cluster algebras.  In type A, his model specializes to the Knutson-Tao hive model.

Comment: He's got a video on this result up, at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pzLJllRyoY